# Angular2 Redirect to Default Page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to redirect default page when refresh page.Before refresh page i'm in here http://localhost/mypage/#/brand , when i refresh page 
i would like to redirect  http://localhost/mypage/#/home

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
     { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },   
     { path: 'home', component: Home },
     { path: 'brand', component: BrandCP },
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = []
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Query string like `?redirect=1` when you go this `brand` page just append the value to redirect accordion to your preference what you want on the next reload then in the component for brand just scant the value of this redirect Query param if it is undefined or set to zero then let him stay on the page else if it is set to 1 then redirect him to home page Plain and simple